# CartScreen Qty value doesn't update in screen or in redux state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, product-quantity

Hey im having issues with my code; my Quantity value wont change after using addToCart function inside a Form of bootstrap.
In the Redux-Devtools it shows in 'action' that the qty is changing; although in the state it isn't. full repository in end of post.

This is the specific Code which captures + addToCart the qty by form in CartScreen.js:

```
      <Form.Control
                      as='select'
                      value={item.qty}
                      onChange={(e) =>
                        dispatch(
                          addToCart(item.product, Number(e.target.value))
                        )
                      }
                    >
                      {[...Array(item.countInStock).keys()].map((x) => (
                        <option key={x + 1} value={x + 1}>
                          {x + 1}
                        </option>
                      ))}
                    </Form.Control>
```

This is the Full CartScreen.js file for full scope.

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { Link, useNavigate, useParams, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import {
  Row,
  Col,
  ListGroup,
  Image,
  Form,
  Button,
  Card,
} from 'react-bootstrap';
import Message from '../components/Message';
import { addToCart } from '../actions/cartActions';

const CartScreen = () => {
  //   const navigate = useNavigate();
  const queryParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
  const qty = queryParams ? Number(queryParams.get('qty')) : 1;
  const { id } = useParams();
  const productId = id;
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const cart = useSelector((state) => state.cart);
  const { cartItems } = cart;

  useEffect(() => {
    if (productId) {
      dispatch(addToCart(productId, qty));
    }
  }, [dispatch, productId, qty]);

  const removeFromCartHandler = (id) => {
    console.log('remove');
  };
  const checkoutHandler = (id) => {
    console.log('remove');
  };

  return (
    <Row>
      <Col md={8}>
        <h1>Shopping Cart</h1>
        {cartItems.length === 0 ? (
          <Message>
            Your cart is empty <Link to='/'>Go Back</Link>
          </Message>
        ) : (
          <ListGroup variant='flush'>
            {cartItems.map((item) => (
              <ListGroup.Item key={item.product}>
                <Row>
                  <Col md={2}>
                    <Image src={item.image} alt={item.name} fluid rounded />
                  </Col>
                  <Col md={3}>
                    <Link to={`/product/${item.product}`}>{item.name}</Link>
                  </Col>
                  <Col md={2}>${item.price}</Col>
                  <Col md={2}>
                    <Form.Control
                      as='select'
                      value={item.qty}
                      onChange={(e) =>
                        dispatch(
                          addToCart(item.product, Number(e.target.value))
                        )
                      }
                    >
                      {[...Array(item.countInStock).keys()].map((x) => (
                        <option key={x + 1} value={x + 1}>
                          {x + 1}
                        </option>
                      ))}
                    </Form.Control>
                  </Col>
                  <Col md={2}>
                    <Button
                      type='button'
                      variant='light'
                      onClick={() => removeFromCartHandler(item.product)}
                    >
                      <i className='fas fa-trash'></i>
                    </Button>
                  </Col>
                </Row>
              </ListGroup.Item>
            ))}
          </ListGroup>
        )}
      </Col>
      <Col md={4}>
        <Card>
          <ListGroup variant='flush'>
            <ListGroup.Item>
              <h2>
                Subtotal ({cartItems.reduce((acc, item) => acc + item.qty, 0)})
                items
              </h2>
              $
              {cartItems
                .reduce((acc, item) => acc + item.qty * item.price, 0)
                .toFixed(2)}
            </ListGroup.Item>
            <ListGroup.Item>
              <Button
                type='button'
                className='btn-block'
                disabled={cartItems.length === 0}
                onClick={checkoutHandler}
              >
                Proceed To Checkout
              </Button>
            </ListGroup.Item>
          </ListGroup>
        </Card>
      </Col>
    </Row>
  );
};

export default CartScreen;
```

I was trying to change the values but nothing helps to change the state, However the CART_ADD_ITEM Function does run on change as supposed to, just Not changing the state or adding to the cart.
I can add the rest of the files here aswell.

Edit:
That's the repository for the full files:
https://github.com/IdanKfir/Proshop